# Looping over an array of images and applying them as background images to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have eight divs like this

```
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail-container"></div>
```

I have an array like this

```
var videoThumbnails = ["video-1-thumbnail.jpg", "video-2-thumbnail.jpg", "video-3-thumbnail.jpg", "video-4-thumbnail.jpg", "video-5-thumbnail.jpg", "video-6-thumbnail.jpg", "video-7-thumbnail.jpg", "video-8-thumbnail.jpg"];
```

Now, I want to loop over those images one by one and apply them as background images to each div. This is what I've done

```
var totalThumbnails = videoThumbnails.length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalThumbnails; i++) {
  $(".video-thumbnail-container:nth-child(" + [i] +")").css({"background-image": "url(img/work/" + videoThumbnails[i] + ")"});
}
```

The code almost works but doesn't apply a background image to the last div. I know I'm making a really silly error here.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't have those square brackets around `i`. That creates an array and it works only because it is implicitly converted to a string with `toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nth-child the index starts at 1 not 0, hence failing try below.

```
var totalThumbnails = videoThumbnails.length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalThumbnails; i++) {
  $(".video-thumbnail-container:nth-child(" + (i+1) +")").css({"background-image": "url(img/work/" + videoThumbnails[i] + ")"});
}
```

Comment: Also, why square brackets? `[i+1]` should be `(i+1)`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm yeah `[1].toString()` prints 1 same as just `1.toString()` on it's own. only difference would be if more then 1 number was specified since square brackets[] are the shorthand for an array in JS which would end up returning them as comma separated values

Comment: @Sarfaraaz Yes but why instantiate an array only to immediately have it converted into a string?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm can you explain what's the difference between using [i+1] and (i+1) ? Because both are working for me.

Comment: @YashGhelani `[i+1]` creates an array with a single item (the result of `i + 1`), then it's concatenated to the string by implicitly invoking the array's `toString()` method. That's why it works but it's inefficient and an inappropriate use of the array syntax. `(i+1)` simply puts `i+1` as its own expression that is evaluated separately before its result is inserted.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm okayy! thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: @Sarfaraaz BTW, `Number.prototype.toString` is NOT used when concatenating a primitive number to a string.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm wuuuuut. that's so interesting. never knew that. makes sense I guess. gonna go look that up.... Ah i see, it's so that you can choose ur number base when getting a string (hexadecimal, binary, base-10 etc) **Nice!**

Comment: @Sarfaraaz Yeah, it's actually the string itself that knows how to convert primitive value types to strings, that's why `toString` isn't needed. Whenever you invoke a method on a primitive value, it's basically a hack internally in Javascript, or syntactic sugar if you will, where it uses the method from the boxed type and acts as if the primitive type has that method.